# Output from request.get(url) looks like dict but says it's a string

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I am new to this so bare with me. This a bioinformatics related question but I don't think that matters.
Here is my code (python):

```
import requests  
URL = 'https://iupred2a.elte.hu/iupred2a/long/P03255.json'  
response = requests.get(URL)  
out = response.content  
out_str = str(out, encoding='UTF-8')
```

the output for this starts and ends with {} and looks like a dictionary however, it says it is type string.

Answer (score 2):

It is a json encoded object, that looks quite similar to a python dictionary, but it's not (it is, as you mentioned, a string).

To get the dictionary, use `.json()` instead of `.content`:

```py
out = response.json()
```

References:

- https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-content
- https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content

Comment: Thank you, just what I need!

Comment: You are welcome! Please accept the answer if it solved the problem.